# Stopping duplicate children or n+1 with nhibernate when using joins

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have a parent class that HasMany children with the mapping:

```
HasMany(x => x.Children).KeyColumn("ParentId");
```

And the repository function as:

```
Parent parent = null;
Child child = null;

var query = Session.QueryOver(() => parent )
.JoinAlias(() => parent.Children, () => child , JoinType.InnerJoin)
.TransformUsing(Transformers.DistinctRootEntity).Skip(skip).Take(25).List();
```

Which works fine except it triggers multiple calls to select children when they are accessed off the parent.

I don't want multiple DB hits so I changed the code to have the mapping as:

```
 HasMany(x => x.Children).KeyColumn("ParentId").Fetch.Join();
```

And removed the join alias completely, which equally works fine except when the parent appears multiple times in the select. For example these are the sql rows that come back from the select query generated:

```
ParentId | ChildId
123      |1
123      |1
124      |2
125      |1
```

But it gets output to objects as Parent with id 123 appearing twice (which is correct) but both have four children with id 1 (which is wrong, it only has one child)

My question is can you have a HasMany without an n+1 occuring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take off the `Fetch.Join` and use batching, from my memory you use `BatchSize`

```
HasMany(x => x.Children).KeyColumn("ParentId").BatchSize(25);
```

As you have found out fetch join is not useful if you are using paging as you will get a cartesian product (duplicates)